# How to get the Cassandra Table/Columnfamily size in MB

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cql

I want to design my cluster and want to set proper size of key_cache and row_cache
depending on the size of the tables/columnfamilies.
Similar to mysql, do we have something like this in Cassandra/CQL?

```
SELECT table_name AS "Tables", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "$DB_NAME";
```

Or any other way to look for the data-size and indexes' size separately.

Or what configuration of each node would be needed to put my table completely in the memory
without considering any replication factor.

Answer (score 1):

The key cache and row caches work rather differently.  It's important to understand the difference for calculating sizes.

The key cache is a cache of offsets within files for locations for rows.  It is basically a map from (key, file) to offset.  Therefore scaling the key cache size depends on number of rows, not overall data size.  You can find the number of rows from the 'Number of keys' parameter in 'nodetool cfstats'.  Note this is per node, not a total, but that's what you want to decide on cache sizes.  The default size is min(5% of Heap (in MB), 100MB), which is probably sufficient for most applications.  A subtlety here is that rows may exist in multiple files (SSTables), the number depending on your write pattern.  However, this duplication is accounted for (approximately) in the estimated count from nodetool.

The row cache caches the actual row.  To get a size estimate for this you can use the 'Space used' parameter in 'nodetool cfstats'.  However, the row cache caches deserialized data and only the latest copy so the size could be quite different (higher or lower).

There is also a third less configurable cache - your OS filesystem cache.  In most cases this is actually better than the row cache.  It avoids duplicating data in memory, because when using the row cache most likely data will be in the filesystem cache too.  And reading from an SSTable in the filesystem cache is only 30% slower than the row cache in my experiments (a while ago, probably not valid any more but unlikely to be significantly different).  The main use case for the row cache is when you have one relatively small CF that you want to ensure is cached.  Otherwise using the filesystem cache is probably the best.

In conclusion, the Cassandra defaults of a large key cache and no row cache are the best for most setups.  You should only play with the caches if you know your access pattern won't work with the defaults or if you're having performance issues.

Comment: Let me tell you my application design. So basically, I have a web service and for every single request application performs around 500<#ofDatabaseQueries<1000. The total num of rows are around a billion and it will keep on increasing over time and each row contains not more than 100 coulmns (in terms of a table) and no column has large data. Obviously, I will be using the cloud and distribute the data among different nodes but for a test purpose, I am using a single node. The best way  I think is to cache all the rows so that the number of DB queries per request can be handled properly.

Comment: The row cache may be a good candidate for this, but you should try to reduce the number of database queries per request if you can.  Cassandra could maybe do 10k reads per second per node, so that's only 10 requests per second per node.

Comment: From where did you get this number 10k reads/sec/node, doesn't it depend on the hardware? It's a good info btw and could you share some links where I can see these kind of performance related info.
The queries/request are not all unique so I guess, the row-cache would be helpful in my case, I am new to cassandra and i am reading everything about it.

Comment: Sure, the performance depends on hardware.  10k reads/s is a rough rule of thumb.  Netflix got about 10k writes/s here: http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/11/benchmarking-cassandra-scalability-on.html.  Reads are a bit slower, there's some benchmarks here showing a few k/s: http://www.networkworld.com/cgi-bin/mailto/x.cgi?pagetosend=/news/tech/2012/102212-nosql-263595.html&pagename=/news/tech/2012/102212-nosql-263595.html&pageurl=http://www.networkworld.com/news/tech/2012/102212-nosql-263595.html&site=printpage&nsdr=n